# Names are trying to escape!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

What's up? Why names are running away from their owners? Why this whitespace?

> [image]

<s>By the way, I understood the reason of this bug ;) Is it related to hatz, because name should be moved depending on how you align your hat. And it is being tested now :)</s>

So it was because of redesigning profile page!..

Comment: Don't take it personal, but they are trying to work you out. Don't let them ;)

Comment: Not just you. They added a `margin-left: 75px;` in the CSS. Yeah, it's ugly.

Comment: Oops. Seems that my image got stretched - can anyone fix it while I am on my phone?

Comment: @Pat Still stretched :D

Comment: Most cell phones has double resolution, so we can't really "fix" that.

Comment: @Sha Yes, "fix", as I finally managed to do :)

Comment: @Pat *now* it is really done :D

Comment: @Oded So I accept Patricks's answer (you won't post anything)?

Comment: That _was_ the cause.

Comment: @Oded I know, but you won't post an answer saying that it is fixed? If you won't, I'll accept Patrick's answer.

Comment: No need... I tagged it ;)

Comment: @Oded it happens again...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this code in the CSS:

```
.user-page .user-show-new #user-displayname
{
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
```

This code isn't on SO for example. If you comment it out, it shows fine:

> [image]

Comment: Fine, now hire as dev and fix it :)

Comment: I guess they're testing new design, and good chance it's on purpose. (i.e. their designer decided it's nicer this way)

Comment: Why did you rollback, Patrick? Adding the quote block make it easier to see it's a screenshot and not text. Too minor to fight for though.

Comment: @Sha: I don't feel it that way, but I value your opinion, so I rolled back.